# java code for sift algorithm

Tags: java, sift, image-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing SIFT in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234517/implementing-sift-in-java)

Hi
I need to compare an image with images in database using sift algorithm
Can anyone tell where I can get java coding for implementing this concept
I am new to java programming and image comparison
Help me complete my project 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at OpenCV - or this [blog post](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/implementing-sift-in-opencv/). The examples there are in C/C++ but you can get Java interface to OpenCV [such as this](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) and write similar code.

Comment: 1) SO is not a code generation machine.  What do you have so far?  Where are you stuck? 2) It pays to ask a question, if you want an answer.